# How to build Visual Studio 2012 Publishing Profiles on a Build Server with MsBuild without installing Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, build-automation, publishing

I read through many of the posts on here and never found a clear answer that worked.   So after spending the time getting this to work, I figured I should post it.

Problem:  The publishing profile would build on the server, but would not publish.

Solution:

1. Make sure you installed [Microsoft Windows SDK and .Net Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
2. From your client machine with Visual Studio 2012 update 2 installed, copy:

> ```
> \Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Visual Studio\v11.0\Web\
> \Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Visual Studio\v11.0\WebApplications\
> ```

To the same location on your server.

Then make a simple batch file:

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" /v:diag
> YOUPROJECT.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DeployOnBuild=true
> /p:PublishProfile=YOURPROFILE

This is working for us on multiple build servers.

I hope this helps someone.

It seems insane to me that Microsoft hasn't provided a MSBuild update with all the publishing options.  It seems to me that the command line tools are more important on the server....

Comment: Should I install a 32 or a 64 bit version of the SDK (assuming build server is a 64 bit itself)?

Comment: I have spent hours trying to figure out why the deployonbuild wasn't firing as part of my msbuild task. This got me going in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I found that by installing the Web Tools 2012.2 update on the build server my DeployOnBuild worked on the server. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20616532/830402

Comment: I suggest you split this into a question and an answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 10):

Just moving Dave's solution into an answer.

> Solution:
>
> 1. Make sure you installed [Microsoft Windows SDK and .Net Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
> 2. From your client machine with Visual Studio 2012 update 2 installed, copy:
>
> > ```
> > \Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Visual Studio\v11.0\Web\
> > \Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Visual Studio\v11.0\WebApplications\
> > ```
>
> To the same location on your server.
>
> Then make a simple batch file:
>
> > "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" /v:diag
> >     YOUPROJECT.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DeployOnBuild=true
> >     /p:PublishProfile=YOURPROFILE
>
> This is working for us on multiple build servers.