# MSBuild with publish profiles and configuration merges

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I made a small ps script to do my web app deployment packages with MSBuild. Since I had already done publishing profiles, I came up with this command line:

```
.\MSBuild.exe "C\path\project.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="C:\path\profile.pubxml" /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

Works great, exect one thing. Web.config merges are not done even if specified in the publish profile.

I tried addding the /p:Configuration=myConfig parameter. But I get some error with an output path not provided

Microsoft lol.. How can I make it work?

Comment: +1 Thanks for mentioning /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 argument, it fixed copying contents of obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp directory when publishing to the desired location specified in the PublishProfile configuration (on a system with both VS2010 and VS2012 installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed VS update 3 on the build server an it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **install**   ***and***   **import**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```

also:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176894/how-to-build-visual-studio-2012-publishing-profiles-on-a-build-server-with-msbui#_=_
```