# TeamCity: How tell MSBuild to take into account publish profile parameters?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have TeamCity build configuration with MSBuild step, when i would like to compile my project with publish profile. My publish profile is located in **MyProject\Properties\PublishProfiles\profile.pubxml**.

**My profile.pubxml:**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>MergeAllOutputsToASingleAssembly</WDPMergeOption>
    <UseMerge>True</UseMerge>
    <SingleAssemblyName>project</SingleAssemblyName>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\DevelopmentFolder</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**My build step:**

```
Runner type: MSBuild
Build file path: MyProject.csproj
MSBuild version: Microsoft Build Tools 2013
MSBuild ToolsVersion: 12
Run platform: x86
```

Now i would like to compile my project with account of parameters from my publish profile. I try to create all parameters as system parameters of build configuration (as in [TeamCity says to use "Build Parameters" instead of "/property:" in an MSBuild step. What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218486/teamcity-says-to-use-build-parameters-instead-of-property-in-an-msbuild-st)), but i think MSBuild does not take into account parameters, because i can't see in **bin** directory **project.dll** file.

Comment: I found solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176894/how-to-build-visual-studio-2012-publishing-profiles-on-a-build-server-with-msbui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add TeamCity property system.PublishProfile and the value should be your pubxml profile name ("profile" in your example). Then add a build step which runs MSBuild with the target "WebPublish" - it works for me.

Comment: This invokes the WebPublish, however, FTP publishing is not yet supported.