# What is the difference between a Publish and a WebPublish target?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

We have a build configuration runner type of **Visual Studio.sln** setup to read from a **csproj** with a Publish Profile **(/P:PublishProfile=%env.Configuration%.pubxml)** to create a Web Deploy Package that we then use in another build step to deploy using MSDeploy.

On TeamCity the Targets options states that

```
Enter targets separated by space or semicolon. Build, Rebuild, Clean, Publish targets are supported by default
```

Looking at some other StackOverflow threads, it mentions that using WebPublish as a target works but doesn't say why it works.

[TeamCity: How tell MSBuild to take into account publish profile parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302074/teamcity-how-tell-msbuild-to-take-into-account-publish-profile-parameters)

I am not sure what the difference between a "Publish" and a "WebPublish" is.

Answer (score 0):

The "Publish" Visual Studio target uses WebDeploy/WebPublish under the hood to do its publishing.

Comment: Specifically, `Publish` will call `WebPublish` if you passed `DeployTarget=WebPublish` or if you passed a value for `PublishProfile`.  See `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets:137`.